# should charge balance be based on activities?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, concentration

We have a fluid with $\pu{0.01 M}~\ce{HCl}$ and $\pu{0.02 M}~\ce{K2HPO4}$, so if we assume activity coefficients are $1$ throughout we can find pH as $6.800012$ and confirm that at that pH there is approximately zero balance ($6.104839\!\times\!10^{-13}$) between positive and negative charges calculated as

$$\mathrm{  K^+ +H^+ – OH^- - Cl^- -}\ce{H2PO4-}\mathrm{ - 2\times} \ce{HPO4^2-} \mathrm{\ -\ 3\ \times}\ce{PO4^3-}$$

Now we can find the ionic strength and via Debye-Hückel/Davies find activity coefficients for absolute charge 1-3. This allows correction of the thermodynamic dissociation coefficients for phosphoric acid (and water dissociation) so we can correct the concentrations and find a new pH to minimize charge balance. After $4$ iterations we have pH 6.436864 at a charge balance of $1.429412\!\times\!10^{-15}$. This procedure allows reproduction of the results in a recent paper (Schell et al J Chem Eng Data 2018; 63: 2151-2161) with correlation $>0.9999$.

Now the question: these results requires the charge balance being formulated strictly in concentrations multi-plied by the relevant charges. I simply wonder why we should not for the charge balance equation multiply the found activity coefficients on the charged species so making the balance to minimize a function of $f_3\times 3\times [\ce{PO4}]$ and so forth with $f_3$ being the trivalent activity coefficient from Davies?

Comment: It doesn't seem strange at all to me.  You are doing a balance of charges, and the charges don't know what activity is.

Comment: Sticking with concentrations certainly gives a perfect fit compared to other methods, but all the literature on single ion activity coefficients for strong ions  made me wonder if the charge should not be discounted. I am happy if that is not the case.

Comment: Would there be any online literature Chester Miller could cite to make it obvious that charges are oblivious to activities?

Comment: I don't know.  But check out Handbook of Aqueous Electrolyte Thermodynamics

Comment: This Handbook of Aqueous Electrolyte Thermodynamics is not available for me  - I would really like a reference if it exists :-) -

Comment: I would have corrected the typesetting, but I do not understand the formula at all. `2*K+H – OH- Cl -H2PO4 - 2*HPO4 - 3*PO4` What exactly are you adding or subtracting there? It is certainly not the elements/ions, but some kind of property of them. Please try to be more precise about this. I still don't understand the question and believe it should remain closed until it can be clarified.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I had the same problem. My guess was concentrations, but its definitely not standard notation and since the rest of the question is about activities, I couldn't be sure.

Comment: So sorry for the confusion - I had a 2 x K in the charge balance, it was all meant to be concentrations  multiplied with charges. Chester Miller mentioned that charges don't know about activities. If so I have no problem. But if in a concentrated fluid Na has activity coeff of say  0.5  I just thought it reasonable to think its charge was also somewhat discounted. But it disturbs certainly the fit to data to make that assumption so I would like to believe it were wrong.

Answer (score 2):

No, charge is not really a activity based property.  It is a number.  Just as the activity coefficients don't change the *number* (or *moles*) of potassium atoms or phosphate anions, they don't change the charge either.

If you told me that one liter of a 1.0 molar potassium chloride solution had activity coefficients of 21 for potassium and 186 for chloride, then the amount of charge in the solution is still one mole of potassium cations and one mole chloride anions.